# HTTP POST request body not binding in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am a starter with ASP.NET MVC. I generated a basic class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MyPluginProject.Models;

namespace MyPluginProject.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        
        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
            return View();
        }
        
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult data(TestRequestObject testRequestObject)
        {
            TestResponseObject respobj = new TestResponseObject();
            
            respobj.id = testRequestObject.Id;
            respobj.name = testRequestObject.Name;
            
            //return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(respobj);
            return Json(respobj);
        }
    }
}
```

and the `TestRequestObject` POCO looks like this:

```
 public class TestRequestObject
 {
     public string Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Address { get; set; }
 }
```

The route config:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
}
```

However when I run this locally and send request from Postman with

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:50132/home/data' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{   
"id": "123456789",
"name": "John Smith",
"address":"ftyrhrrhrhhr"
}'
```

the value is not getting bound to the `TestRequestObject`. I tried `[FromBody]`, however it's only allowed for .NET Core it seems. I don't seem to understand as to what is going wrong here.

**UPDATE:-**

I tried this in a new MVC C# class that i created and the same binding set up works flawlessly.As i told it was also working on my project but some change while playing around has messed up some internal binding thing.I dont know what.Could anyone having faced any such issue guide me on this?

Comment: Look fine for me [Postman image](https://imgur.com/2Fj3e9g), [Visual Studio Debug](https://imgur.com/igyRQbQ)

Comment: Looks fine to me, how are you defining your `JSON` when you are sending it through postman?

Comment: The curl command i have posted is the same way i am sending the json from my postman

Comment: @sand87 Your model looks correct and so is your API method. It could only be the way you are calling the API via curl command that is giving the incorrect result.

Comment: Kindly address the two obvious questions, Does it invoke the action? What is the response (it should be 500 Server Error I guess due to NRE)

Comment: Its strange actually.It gave a 200 Ok status code and the response body had the id and address but the value was null.On debugging i found that the values sent via curl wasnt getting bound even though the api was called.I guess one other better option could be adding to the route.config file.That probably could address this

Answer (score 1):

try to use /x-www-form-urlencoded content type

```
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'id=123456789' \
--data-urlencode 'name=John Smith'
```

if it still is not working , add [FromForm] attribute. If you want to use json for mvc5 you will have to write tonns of code to make a special decriptor

Comment: I created a new project and in that it worked.However in my current project that i have mentioned here and since has grown bigger i yet have to implement a workaround.Any idea as to what setting or which file i need to look in a .NET MVC framework to fix such an issue so that i can get rid of the workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Try sending POST request this way.

`curl -d '{json}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://example.com/login`

Comment: i will try this

Answer (score 0):

firstly you should use     [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")] Tag in upon of your controller class in order to rout URL to this block of your code

```
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    { 
     ...
```

secondly you are starter in asp , i suggest you that you use Swagger to generate better ui and help you to send HTTTP request in correct format to Webapplication , for adding swagger to your project follow below  :

[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvwvFmO-56E)

Comment: @Fazal Yes i had tried this but actually my route has Home/[controller]/[action] and thats why the api at the front didnt work in my case.I am not saying that my answer above is the best option.Actually as i said it should ideally bind without having to add all this code.However whatever i did the TestObject  contents would be null and only this seemed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case finally i had to write a model binding to resolve this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MyPluginProject.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace MyPluginProject.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            
            return View();
        }
        
        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
        
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Data([ModelBinder(typeof(JsonNetModelBinder))]  TestRequestObject testRequestObject)
        {
            TestResponseObject respobj = new TestResponseObject();
            
                respobj.id = testRequestObject.Id;
                respobj.name = testRequestObject.Name;
            
            //return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(respobj);
            return Json(respobj);
               
        }
   
    }


    internal class JsonNetModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
            var stream = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream;
            var readStream = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
            var json = readStream.ReadToEnd();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, bindingContext.ModelType);
        }
    }
}
```

With this i am able to get the request body from postman bound to the model